# Jquery Slider UL - multiple filters

Tags: jquery, slider

I try to create advanced search engine based on jQuery slider.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L4xAm/1/)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#slider_powcalk").slider({
        range:true,
        min: 0,
        max: 1000,
        step: 5,
        values: [100, 900],
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            for (var i = 0; i < ui.values.length; ++i) {
                $("input.slider_powcalk_Value[data-index=" + i + "]").val(ui.values[i]);
            }
        }
    });

    $("input.slider_powcalk_Value").change(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $("#slider_powcalk").slider("values", $this.data("index"), $this.val());
    });
});
```

I want to run multiple sliders on single page and each width two values (inputs) 
How can i run second slider to keep clear code (i dont wnat to copy all code and change class only)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that your example duplicates IDs (which must be unique), however that doesn't cause any issues with the code.

To do what you want, try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#slider_powcalk, #slider_sso").each(function () {
        var value = parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
        $(this).empty().slider({
            range: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 1000,
            step: 5,
            values: [100, 900],
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                for (var i = 0; i < ui.values.length; ++i) {
                    $(this).parent().find("input[data-index=" + i + "]").val(ui.values[i]);
                }
            }
        });
    });
    $("input.slider_powcalk_Value").change(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $("#slider_powcalk").slider("values", $this.data("index"), $this.val());
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/L4xAm/3/)**

I added `#slider_sso` to your slider instantiation to get `$("#slider_powcalk, #slider_sso").slider({` and updated the value in the slide event to `$(this).parent().find("input[data-index=" + i + "]")`.

Comment: There is one issue. When i move first slider , then second and rirst again the first slider take the value from second..Have you got any solution ?